# How to update rows with their own values SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with multiple rows and two columns, one called title and the other meta_title

Example:

```
table: users

before
row: id = 1, title = 'koen', meta_title = ''

after
row: id = 1, title = 'koen', meta_title = 'koen'
```

How do I update the meta_title with the title column for each row?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: your question does not make any Sense

Comment: Are you simply concatenating title and name ? If so I would not do this in the table.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Do you know the syntax for an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: I changed name to meta_title

Comment: I know the UPDATE statement but i need to update 800 items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use column names on both sides of the assignment operator:

```sql
UPDATE users
SET    meta_title = title
```

Comment: Is it possible to concatenate title with an other string ? Like UPDATE users SET meta_title = title"+var+"

Comment: @SaadElQorchi yes, you can use the `concat` function: `UPDATE users SET meta_title = CONCAT(title, 'some other string or column')`.